# export database Oracle with maven

Tags: java, oracle, maven, export

I've a maven project, and I would like to do an database operation before the `scope <test>`.

I want to connect to a distant database, **export some table to a String format**, and inject in my local database.

have you any way to do that ?

Comment: One way would be to write an own maven plugin. Have you considered it?

Comment: You could have a look at [DBUnit](http://mojo.codehaus.org/dbunit-maven-plugin/index.html)

Comment: @cy3er : not really, I've begin with maven this summer ^^

Comment: @user3819021 : DBUnit seems very good, but he isn't on my repository.. And my entreprise say "find solution with existing dependencies" ...

Comment: I can't find a way to say to maven : "take this property file, connect to the database, and save all tuples in a fic.sql for put that tuples in another database" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For somebody.
I've resovled by this way : use jdbc, and run my class with Maven.. Not very nice, but efficient.